# how to repeat same test suite for multiple time with different url

Tags: webdriver-io

I have a webapp which supports multiple language
based on the query params it loads in different lang

for ex : `http://eeee.com/home?lang=US` will load in english and `http://eeee.com/home?lang=french`

I have automation code written for english
I need to run the same code for all other language as well

something like

```
"test-english": "./node_modules/.bin/wdio wdio.conf.js --lang=US"
```

should run for english

```
"test-french": "./node_modules/.bin/wdio wdio.conf.js --lang=fr"
```

should run for french

or atleast first it should run all test for english and then for french

my wdio.conf.js

looks like

```
exports.config = {
    specs: [
        './test/**/*.test.js'
    ],
    baseUrl: 'http://eeee.com/',
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Inorder to have custom option in wdio we can use something like this in wdio.conf.js

```
onPrepare: function(config, capabilities) {
    if (process.argv !== undefined && process.argv.length) {
        process.argv.forEach(arg => {
            if (arg.indexOf('--lang=') !== -1) {
                process.env.lang = arg.replace('--lang=', '');
            }
        });
    }
},
before: function(capabilities, specs) {
    global.lang = process.env.lang;
}
```